# Best way to retrieve data using EF.Core GroupBy(); or alternatives

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I'm starting to build a KPI (key performance indicators) dashboard, and I'm struggling to find the most optimized way to do so. Suggestions are welcome.

I was trying to use only LINQ (in EF Core 3.1).

In my model **1 ProductionRecord** can have **N ProductionCellRecords**. I was trying to do something like this (group all records from last year and sum the Good Components, etc...):

```
            var data = _context.ProductionRecords
                .Where(pr => pr.StartedAt < DateTime.Now &&
                    pr.StartedAt.AddDays(365) >= DateTime.Now)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(pr => pr.StartedAt.Month)
                .Select(g => new { name = g.Key,
                    goodComponents = g.Select(pr => pr.ProductionCellRecords.Sum(pcr => pcr.GoodComponents)),
                    badComponents = g.Select(pr => pr.ProductionCellRecords.Sum(pcr => pcr.BadComponents)) });
```

But the `g.Select(pr => pr.ProductionCellRecords.Sum(pcr => pcr.GoodComponents))` is not returning the Sum, but `{System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectIListIterator<NoPaper.Models.ProductionRecord, int>}` instead. Anyways I found `GroupBy` doesn't work the same as SQL `GroupBy` unless it has an aggregation function in it. This seems to lead to limitations perfomance-wise, IMO.

**Q:** So I was wondering what am I doing wrong in the above query, and what's the best/most optimized way to query the database so it answers my needs.

**MY MODEL/CLASS**

```
public class ProductionRecord
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartedAt { get; set; }
        ...
        public ICollection<ProductionCellRecord> ProductionCellRecords { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ProductionCellRecord
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductionRecordId { get; set; }
        ...
        public ProductionRecord ProductionRecord { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Remove `.AsEnumerable()`, it's causing the `GroupBy` to be executed in memory rather than translated to SQL.

Comment: @IvanStoev If I do so, I will get a `could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()` error

Comment: Take the first advice from the error *"rewrite the query in a form that can be translated"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written query which cannot be translated. GroupBy has serious limitations and cannot be used as it is possible with LINQ to Objects.

```cs
var query = 
    from pr in _context.ProductionRecords
    from pcr in pr.ProductionCellRecords
    where pr.StartedAt < DateTime.Now && pr.StartedAt.AddDays(365) >= DateTime.Now
    group pcr by pr.StartedAt.Month into g
    select new 
    { 
        name = g.Key,
        goodComponents = g.Sum(x => x.GoodComponents),
        badComponents = g.Sum(x => x.BadComponents) 
    }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Just a pointer to exchange the where clause to: `where pr.StartedAt < DateTime.Now && pr.StartedAt.AddDays(365) >= DateTime.Now`